# Gnuplot Expand Plot to Fill Area

Tags: gnuplot

I am making a video for my simulation, where each each frame is a picture of the simulation, and a graph. I'm making the graph with gnuplot, and I first run the simulation to determine the x and y ranges to use and then hardcode the range into the plot script. It works okay, but the plot does not use up the entire surface, there is a ton of white space, and the plot is only about 1/4 of the total area. Is there a way to make the plot expand closer to the edges of the boundary, or a way to control the plot placement?

Script:

```
set term postscript eps color enhanced "Helvetica" 36
set output 'image.eps'
set size ratio 0.8
set logscale x
set xlabel 'Time(Arb. Units)'
set xrange [10:100000]
set yrange [0:1.6]
set y2range [0:0.5]
set ylabel 'Absorption(%)'
set y2label 'Emission'
set format x '%.0e'
set xtics 10, 100, 100000
set key noautotitles
plot 'absorption.dat' axes x1y1 w lines lt 3 lw 5, 'emission.dat' axes x1y2 w lines lt 1 lw 5
```

Here is what comes out:
[image]

I set a grey background so you can see what space is being wasted.

Edit: I've also tried the png terminal, but that seems to make the problem even worse. The plot is shrunk even further. I replaced the top two lines of the script with:

```
set term png font Helvetica 36
set output 'image.png'
```

Then this is what comes out:
[image]

Comment: in png you're probably using a too big font or too small size of the png image. Type `help png` to get all options

Comment: I would also suggest to issu the command `set ytics nomirror` to avoid spurious tics on the y2 axe

Comment: by default png size is 640x480, I usually use `set term png enhanced transparent crop size 1200,900`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things involved in the computation of the plot size:

1. Different terminals have different default canvas sizes. If the defaults don't fit your needs, change the size `set terminal ... size ...`
2. The canvas has a fixed aspect ratio (given by the terminals size settings) and you impose an additional constraint with `set size ratio...` which affects only the plot but not the canvas size. So, if you need this size ratio you must adapt the plot canvas to it.
3. A third parameter are the margins. Since gnuplot don't exactly know how the labels will be rendered by the terminal, the margins cannot be exact. You can set margins manually with `set bmargin ...` (for the bottom margin) and equivalently for the other margins.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a terminal that accept the `crop` flag
e.g. `png`, `gif`, `jpeg` but also `epscairo`

Comment: I was running into other issues with the png terminal. For some reason the size of the plot is significantly different depending on what terminal I use. See edits.

Comment: Yes, different drivers produce different output, it's partly because gnuplot is a collaborative project and relies on third party libraries which do not always use the same structure. Moreover in `png` is a raster image format while `eps`is vector graphics: very different approach. Nevertheless things are getting better and better.